# Marking up implicit column header for accessibility in HTML

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

I'm providing a table of data which will roughly look like this:

```
|                   |  2009  |  2010  |  2011  |
| location 1        |  pass  |  pass  |  fail  |
| location 2        |  fail  |  pass  |  pass  |
```

For normally sighted readers, the meaning of the first column - location names - is clear and it looks better visually to leave off the column header. However, that's not helpful to people using a screen reader, and, unsurprisingly, fails WAI validation.

My markup looks like:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>&nbsp;</th> <!-- question here -->
     <th>2009</th>
     <th>2010</th>
     <th>2011</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 ...
```

So my question is: what should I add to the indicated `th` so that it will provide support and context for people who need it, but won't add visual clutter for people who don't?

One option I have thought of is to add the column title to the markup, but then render it invisible using CSS for sighted readers. However, I wonder if there's a better (more semantic) way using ARIA metadata or something similar?

Comment: Just mark the `<th>&nbsp;</th>` as `<td>&nbsp;</td>`

Comment: But semantically it's a header cell, not a data cell. In particular, I want to set `scope='col'`, which I don't think will validate (or, be useful) on a `td` element.

Comment: How is it a header cell? It provides no context to the table. `scope=col` would be inappropriate because that would say Location 1 & 2 are grouped    by " " <- a space character, which most AT ignore.

Comment: But that's exactly the point. I want to annotate the column with something that will be help users relying on screen readers, while not adding distraction for other users.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Column 1, cell 1 should be: `<td>&nbsp;</td>`

*Note this is not an answer per say, I needed more formating space*

Ian left [the following comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041646/marking-up-implicit-column-header-for-accessibility-in-html?noredirect=1#comment24714912_17041646):

> But that's exactly the point. I want to annotate the column with something that will be help users relying on screen readers, while not adding distraction for other users

...but why? 99% of the tables I have seen, leave this cell blank,  so you're not throwing a wrench into the bag.

Using CSS to hide text to add "this cell is intentionally left blank" adds *next to no* value. It adds useless banter that people have to listen to. Further, people who use screen readers on a daily basis do not usually read cell by cell. When they encounter a table, the assistive tech announces the number of cols and rows, and then the summary (see below) then the `<caption>`.

If you want to describe the table in this cell; ex: *(Table has data containing xxx from dates from - to. blah blah blah)*, don't. The old way was to use the `summary` attribute (`<table summary='...'>`). The W3c validator now says

> "The summary attribute is obsolete. Consider describing the structure of the table in a caption element or in a figure element containing the table; or, simplify the structure of the table so that no description is needed."

when you use HTML5.

From some quick research [[1](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200909/html_5_and_the_summary_attribute/)],[[2](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-a11y/2009Nov/thread.html#msg47)],[[3](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/SummaryForTABLE)], it looks like the above the validator error is getting that from the [WorkingGroup decision from April 2011](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Apr/0091.html). My gut they suggested using `<caption>` tag is so more people can gain access to it, ala be more Universally Designed. I didn't see anything for or against saying you could not use `aria-describedby="{ID}"`, and push that paragraph off-screen.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. However, adding "this cell is intentionally blank" isn't what I'm trying to achieve, because that won't help screen reader users, as far as I understand the issue. I've added an answer with the way I'm currently addressing the issue, so that hopefully makes it clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Now that you are putting data in that cell vs `&nbsp;`, you shouldn't hide it

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, where were you checking it for WAI validation? I only ask because putting your code into [this web accessibility checker](http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php) doesn't produce any errors. So it seems like what you have may be viable.

In any case, it looks like the guys over at WebAIM have a similar [example](http://webaim.org/articles/jaws/tables.htm) in their tables (toward the bottom) and they simply use `<td>&nbsp;</td>` instead of `th`.

The more important aspect is using the `scope` attribute in each `th` to make sure it points to either the column or row it is corresponding with. For example:

```
<th scope="col">2009</th>
```

and

```
<th scope="row">location 1</th>
```

More information can be found [here](http://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data) in their article.

Comment: Wave (http://www.webaim.org) reports "Empty table header. A table header (<th>) contains no text". Wave is widely used as a WAI compliance checker, and, more importantly, is the one my client is checking with!

Comment: My comment above essentially echos what WAVE said, and I didn't check it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm solving this at the moment is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope='col'><span class='nodisplay'>Location</span></th>
    <th scope='col'>2009</th>
    <th scope='col'>2010</th>
    <th scope='col'>2011</th>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

and then:

```
.nodisplay {
  position:absolute;
  left:-10000px;
  top:auto;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

so I'm hiding content from sighted readers rather than adding content for users accessing the content via a screen reader. But I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: Sure you can do that. I probably would advocate not hiding it for usibility purposes.

Comment: But, as you said, "99% of the tables I have seen, leave this cell blank". It's a visual distraction for sighted readers, who can simply eyeball the column and tell what it's about.